# getdate tsql question

Tags: t-sql

How do I write TSQL that it calculates the following:

1. the current date and mid night such as 2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
2. the current date and 6pm such as 2010-12-01 18:00:00.000

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like the following

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS DateNoTime, 
    DATEADD(hh, 18, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS DateNewTime
```

Answer (score 4):

1. `dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0, getDate()),0)`
2. `dateadd(hh,18 + (24 *datediff(dd,0, getDate())),0)`

Comment: I think #2 has a problem.  I think the 3rd parameter of the DATEADD (date expression) isn't working.

Comment: @bobs, oops, I had the number and date params backwards :o -- I still keep it down to two function calls vs 3, though.